# How to draw isometric view of this shape?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, drawings

I'm having trouble drawing an isometric view of this shape:

[image]

I've only just started an engineering course and so far it's involved a lot of drawing which I usually can do but I can't seem to figure out how to 'place' this object to make an isometric view. Am I able to make the base of the object in my drawing whichever face I want?, as I feel perhaps if I rotate it so that the face with the hole is facing the ground might make it easier to draw, or do I have to use the 20x20 square as the base like it is in the current view.

This is also kind of confusing me as well in regards to drawing it in parallel oblique view but that's another issue I guess which I'll probably be able to figure out once I wrap my head around how to attempt the isometric view.

The other shapes I've drawn (see [example](https://imgur.com/a/xsm2r)) felt a lot easier to simply start and don't mess with my brain like this particular shape does. It isn't being marked but I still want to understand how to do it since I'll probably have to deal with these types of shapes later on anyway and would rather have the basics down now.

I'm sorry if my explanation doesn't make sense but I'm not really sure how to word my issue at the moment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please insert the images into your question instead of relying on links to external images. You will need to [edit] your question.

Comment: I followed the formatting it shows for adding images but it is still not showing it. Although when you right click the alt-text and select open image in new tab it shows it

Comment: I tried to edit the post to incldue the pics, but jpg is not supported. you can convert into png and upload the images, external hosting is not required. Clicking on the image icon in the editor lets you supply a link or image file.

Comment: Also maybe I'm stupid now but the first image you provided is isometric?

Comment: @mart no its just orthographic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think, look at the numbers! Drawing isometric, or any projective images for that matter is very straightforward. Just as long as you do not try to find a trick to make it easier. Just work out the distance numbers.

Start by sketching your primary axes. These are the directions you are going to measure against in all parallel projections.

[image]

Then start measuring lines along those directions according to your measurements. Do not try to eye them just measure one axis at a time. So for example from the bottom back corner to the top corner there is 40 units, to the beginning if the miter theres another 40 in the -30 degree direction (axis toward right)

[image]

Just continue mechanically form there to measure all known points. First one plane then from that plane and so on. Don't worry about the circle at first, just find its center and radius as if it were a box. Just faithfully measure units on your ruler (or whatever your drawing software if any is using)

[image]

Don't worry about hiding lines, you can do that later.

[image]

Then once you have one or a few solids done. Hide some lines to make things clearer to see. If you missed any lines it will become apparent at this point.

[image]

Then block the next solid. Now you need to use some draftsman's assumptions in the circle, a draftsman would assume the circle is in middle of the shape at least vertically form that image.

[image]

And finally:

[image]

Comment: Wow that was so simple, thank you so much.

I realise my main issue was from the very beginning, I was making my 30 degree axes go the opposite direction because so far all the shapes i've drawn worked that way (ie. the 'V' you drew is pointing upwards whereas I've been making mine point downwards, which gave me difficulty figuring out how to fit the base into it.)

Thank you for actually explaining it as well rather than just simply drawing it as well, I really appreciate it and will be able to do these types of solids from now on.

Comment: Actually I have to ask, it may be a silly question, but are we allowed to make our isometric projection axis go in the negative 30degrees plane (like in your example drawing). Every example I've seen so far have the axis in a +30degree V shape. Is this just a coincidence?

Comment: @jpmontoya Sure, it does not matter, same thing. actually tha same thing works even  if you rotate the axes or use arbitrary scales and directions.

Comment: Oh and PS it took considerably less time to make the pictures than write the text.

Comment: Thanks again, just wondering, how would you go about drawing this in a general parallel oblique view? I'm having trouble deciding which face to start with.